# Speak typed keystrokes/letters on Mac

Tags: macos, voice

I would like a way for my Mac to give me sound feedback with the letter I type when I type it. For example, if I press the letter "J", a voice should say "J". If I type the number "1", the voice should say "one".

Is this possible on macOS?

The reason I want to do this is because I am copying some numbers into a document from another document, and I want to ensure that I did not mistype a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by temporarily enabling VoiceOver.

1. Open System Preferences > Accessibility > VoiceOver and tick the checkbox to enable VoiceOver.
2. In the dialog that appears, click "Use VoiceOver".
3. Click on the text field where you would like to input data, and begin to type.

Each keystroke you press will be spoken aloud by default.

When you're done, simply uncheck the VoiceOver checkbox in System Preferences. VoiceOver can also be toggled with the  <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> shortcut.